# BlackBerry - Disable cut,copy and paste option and disable screenshots option

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

In my blackberry application, i want to disable cut,copy and paste option on edittext and other html contents. And also i need to disable to capturing screenshots of the screens in the application.

Thanks
Mindus

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
super(NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | 262144); // 262144 NO_SYSTEM_MENU_ITEMS
```

This will hide the default menu items.
Also refer the following [link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/4-7-Removing-Switch-application-menu-item/td-p/241967)

Comment: i can able to hide the default menu item. But i want to disable cut/copy/paste option through buttons. for example the text from the exitfield i can able to select and copy through press button shift + scroll and alt + enter. I need to disable this option.

Comment: thats a device property. I dont think so its possible.